# Remove a website from your Bing Webmaster Tools account which is not in the overview?

Tags: bing-webmaster-tools

[Here](https://moz.com/community/q/how-to-remove-a-website-from-your-bing-webmaster-tools-account) is some info about removing a website from Bing Webmaster. It is very easy, you just select the site in the list and click delete.

[image]

But in my case, the website is not showing up in the overview.

I keep on getting these emails though:

> Dear Webmaster,
>
> This is a monthly report on the open issues categories we have
>   detected on your site.
>
> `http://example.com/` Crawl Errors        1 Please visit the Bing Webmaster
>   Tools at your convenience for detailed information.
>
> Thanks, Bing Webmaster Team
>
> To unsubscribe or change the frequency of this message, please visit
>   the Bing Webmaster Tools to update your preference.

And I don't want to turn off messages from Bing Webmaster altogether. I could filter out emails from Webmaster containing example.com but that's not really nice either.

I don't have access to the domain name any more.

Is there a way to remove this domain name, which doesn't show in the list, from Bing Webmaster?

Comment: Ouch that image hurts my eyes.

Comment: True that! I just learned how to get smaller size images. And I learned a bit more about the Gimp.
I hope it hurts less now.